# Program stops after couple first lines after creating text file. Do not know why, need assistance

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, crash, text-files

I have to make a quiz game for a project, and the program stops after line 12. Anybody know why? the code has comments in it to understand it, basically the program just stops, but doesn't close when it gets to the 12th line of code and I can't understand why. can any of you guys help with that? I'm pretty sure the rest of it is fine. Thanks. Also, the print statements that just print 1, or 2 were just checks to see where the program stopped, it didn't even get to the first one.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Quiz{

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    QuizFile quizFile = new QuizFile();

    quizFile.createQuestions();
    System.out.println("hi");
    System.out.println("1");
    //opens the file
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println("2");
    String line;
    //creates the ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> listOfQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();

        int lineCounter = 0;
    //counts how many lines there are in the file
    while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){
      lineCounter++;
    }
    System.out.println("3");

    //adds the quesitons in the file to the ArrayList by reading specific lines to the list
    for (int lineIndex = 1; lineIndex <= lineCounter; lineIndex++){
      if (lineIndex == 1){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        listOfQuestions.add(line);
      }
      if (lineIndex == 10){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        listOfQuestions.add(line);
      }
      if (lineIndex == 18){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        listOfQuestions.add(line);
      }
      if (lineIndex == 27){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        listOfQuestions.add(line);
      }
      if (lineIndex == 36){
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
        listOfQuestions.add(line);
      }
      else{
        line = inputFile.nextLine();
      }
    }
    System.out.println("4");

    inputFile.close();
    System.out.println("5");

    inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Harry Potter Quiz! Good Luck!");

    /*This is the setup for all of the questions, it works the same way for each question.
    First, a question object is created, the question is read, and then displayed. Then
    the answers are read, and displayed. Then the user answers the question, which is loggged
    and the correct answer is retrieved from the file, as well as times tried and times correct.
    When the user answers the question, a loop tests if it is a valid iput. If not, then the user
    is asked again for a valid input until one is achieved.
    */
    //Question 0
    System.out.println("Question 0:");
    Question question0 = new Question();
    question0.getQuestion();
    System.out.println(question0.question);
    System.out.println("Answers:");
    int question0NumberOfChoices = question0.getNumberOfChoices();
    question0.getAnswers();
    for(int j = 0; j < question0.numberOfChoices; j++){
      System.out.println(j + ":" + question0.answers[j]);
    }
    int question0CorrectAnswer = question0.getCorrectAnswer();
    int question0TimesTried = question0.getTimesTried();
    int question0TimesCorrect = question0.getTimesCorrect();
    int question0Answer;
    do {
      question0Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (question0Answer > (question0.numberOfChoices - 1) && question0Answer < 0);

    //Question 1
    System.out.println("Question 1:");
    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.getQuestion();
    System.out.println(question1.question);
    System.out.println("Answers:");
    int question1NumberOfChoices = question1.getNumberOfChoices();
    question1.getAnswers();
    for(int j = 0; j < question1.numberOfChoices; j++){
      System.out.println(j + ":" + question1.answers[j]);
    }
    int question1CorrectAnswer = question1.getCorrectAnswer();
    int question1TimesTried = question1.getTimesTried();
    int question1TimesCorrect = question1.getTimesCorrect();
    int question1Answer;
    do {
      question1Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (question1Answer > (question1.numberOfChoices - 1) && question1Answer < 0);

    //Question2
    System.out.println("Question 2:");
    Question question2 = new Question();
    question2.getQuestion();
    System.out.println(question2.question);
    System.out.println("Answers:");
    int question2NumberOfChoices = question2.getNumberOfChoices();
    question2.getAnswers();
    for(int j = 0; j < question2.numberOfChoices; j++){
      System.out.println(j + ":" + question2.answers[j]);
    }
    int question2CorrectAnswer = question2.getCorrectAnswer();
    int question2TimesTried = question2.getTimesTried();
    int question2TimesCorrect = question2.getTimesCorrect();
    int question2Answer;
    do {
      question2Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (question2Answer > (question2.numberOfChoices - 1) && question2Answer < 0);

    //Question 3
    System.out.println("Question 3:");
    Question question3 = new Question();
    question3.getQuestion();
    System.out.println(question3.question);
    System.out.println("Answers:");
    int question3NumberOfChoices = question3.getNumberOfChoices();
    question3.getAnswers();
    for(int j = 0; j < question3.numberOfChoices; j++){
      System.out.println(j + ":" + question3.answers[j]);
    }
    int question3CorrectAnswer = question3.getCorrectAnswer();
    int question3TimesTried = question3.getTimesTried();
    int question3TimesCorrect = question3.getTimesCorrect();
    int question3Answer;
    do {
      question3Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (question3Answer > (question3.numberOfChoices - 1) && question3Answer < 0);

    //Question 4
    System.out.println("Question 4:");
    Question question4 = new Question();
    question4.getQuestion();
    System.out.println(question4.question);
    System.out.println("Answers:");
    int question4NumberOfChoices = question4.getNumberOfChoices();
    question4.getAnswers();
    for(int j = 0; j < question4.numberOfChoices; j++){
      System.out.println(j + ":" + question4.answers[j]);
    }
    int question4CorrectAnswer = question4.getCorrectAnswer();
    int question4TimesTried = question4.getTimesTried();
    int question4TimesCorrect = question4.getTimesCorrect();
    int question4Answer;
    do {
      question4Answer = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (question4Answer > (question4.numberOfChoices - 1) && question4Answer < 0);

    //end of quesitons
    //results

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Let's see how you did!");
    int numberOfCorrectAnswers = 0;
    int numberofQuestions = listOfQuestions.size();

    /*For this part, there are 5 pieces that are the same. For each question, the program
    prints the question, the correct answer, and the answer the user chose. Then it checks if the user
    got it right, if so, it tells them, and if not, it also tells them. Then the program displays the
    times the user got it right, and the percentage of how many times they got it right
    */

    System.out.println(listOfQuestions.get(0));
    System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + question0CorrectAnswer);
    System.out.println("Your answer was: " + question0Answer);
    if(question0Answer == question0CorrectAnswer){
      System.out.println("You got it right!");
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, you got it wrong.");
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of times you got it correct: " + question0TimesCorrect);
    System.out.println("Amount of tiems you tried it: " + question0TimesTried);
    float question0Percentage;
    if (question0TimesTried == 0){
      question0Percentage = 0;
    }
    else{
      question0Percentage = question0TimesCorrect / question0TimesTried;
    }    System.out.println("Percentage right: " + question0Percentage);


    System.out.println(listOfQuestions.get(1));
    System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + question1CorrectAnswer);
    System.out.println("Your answer was: " + question1Answer);
    if(question1Answer == question1CorrectAnswer){
      System.out.println("You got it right!");
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, you got it wrong.");
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of times you got it correct: " + question1TimesCorrect);
    System.out.println("Amount of tiems you tried it: " + question1TimesTried);
    float question1Percentage;
    if (question1TimesTried == 0){
      question1Percentage = 0;
    }
    else{
      question1Percentage = question1TimesCorrect / question1TimesTried;
    }
    System.out.println("Percentage right: " + question1Percentage);


    System.out.println(listOfQuestions.get(2));
    System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + question2CorrectAnswer);
    System.out.println("Your answer was: " + question2Answer);
    if(question2Answer == question2CorrectAnswer){
      System.out.println("You got it right!");
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, you got it wrong.");
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of times you got it correct: " + question2TimesCorrect);
    System.out.println("Amount of tiems you tried it: " + question2TimesTried);
    float question2Percentage;
    if (question2TimesTried == 0){
      question2Percentage = 0;
    }
    else{
      question2Percentage = question2TimesCorrect / question2TimesTried;
    }    System.out.println("Percentage right: " + question2Percentage);


    System.out.println(listOfQuestions.get(3));
    System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + question3CorrectAnswer);
    System.out.println("Your answer was: " + question3Answer);
    if(question3Answer == question3CorrectAnswer){
      System.out.println("You got it right!");
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, you got it wrong.");
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of times you got it correct: " + question3TimesCorrect);
    System.out.println("Amount of tiems you tried it: " + question3TimesTried);
    float question3Percentage;
    if (question3TimesTried == 0){
      question3Percentage = 0;
    }
    else{
      question3Percentage = question3TimesCorrect / question3TimesTried;
    }    System.out.println("Percentage right: " + question3Percentage);


    System.out.println(listOfQuestions.get(4));
    System.out.println("The correct answer is: " + question4CorrectAnswer);
    System.out.println("Your answer was: " + question4Answer);
    if(question4Answer == question4CorrectAnswer){
      System.out.println("You got it right!");
      numberOfCorrectAnswers++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, you got it wrong.");
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of times you got it correct: " + question4TimesCorrect);
    System.out.println("Amount of tiems you tried it: " + question4TimesTried);
    float question4Percentage;
    if (question4TimesTried == 0){
      question4Percentage = 0;
    }
    else{
      question4Percentage = question4TimesCorrect / question4TimesTried;
    }    System.out.println("Percentage right: " + question4Percentage);

    /*This puts the percentages of correct questions into an array,
    and then finds the highest and lowest one, and then displays both to the user
    */

    float[] percentages = new float[5];
    percentages[0] = question0Percentage;
    percentages[1] = question1Percentage;
    percentages[2] = question2Percentage;
    percentages[3] = question3Percentage;
    percentages[4] = question4Percentage;

    float bestQuestion = percentages[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < percentages.length; index++){
      if(percentages[index] > bestQuestion){
        bestQuestion = percentages[index];
      }
    }

    float worstQuestion = percentages[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < percentages.length; index++){
      if(percentages[index] < worstQuestion){
        worstQuestion = percentages[index];
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Your worst percentage correct of a question was: " + worstQuestion);
    System.out.println("Your best percentage correct of a question was: " + bestQuestion);



  }
}

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question{

  public String question;
  public int numberOfChoices;
  public int answerChoice;
  public int timesTried;
  public int timesCorrect;
  public String[] answers;

  public String getQuestion() throws IOException{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    question = inputFile.nextLine();
    return question;
  }

  public int getNumberOfChoices() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    numberOfChoices = inputFile.nextInt();
    return numberOfChoices;
  }

  public String[] getAnswers() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    String[] answers = new String[numberOfChoices];
    for(int index = 0; index < numberOfChoices; index++){
      answers[index] = inputFile.nextLine();
    }
    return answers;
  }

  public int getCorrectAnswer() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    answerChoice = inputFile.nextInt();
    return answerChoice;
  }

  public int getTimesTried() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    timesTried = inputFile.nextInt();
    return timesTried;

  }

  public int getTimesCorrect() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("Questions.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    timesCorrect = inputFile.nextInt();
    return timesCorrect;
  }

}

import java.io.*;
public class QuizFile{

  public static void main (String[] args){

  }
  public void createQuestions() throws IOException{

    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Questions.txt");

    outputFile.println("What is the only antidote to basilisk venom?");
    outputFile.println("4");
    outputFile.println("Phoenix Tears");
    outputFile.println("Dragon's Blood");
    outputFile.println("A Bezoar");
    outputFile.println("Mandrake Draught");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");

    outputFile.println("How many times was Nearly Headless Nick hit in the head with a blunt axe?");
    outputFile.println("3");
    outputFile.println("34");
    outputFile.println("45");
    outputFile.println("20");
    outputFile.println("1");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");

    outputFile.println("What magical object causes people to turn orange or sprout tentacle-like warts?");
    outputFile.println("4");
    outputFile.println("Metamorph-Medals");
    outputFile.println("Decoy Detonators");
    outputFile.println("The Mirror Of Erised");
    outputFile.println("U-No-Poo");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");

    outputFile.println("How does Felix Felicis behave when in the cauldron?");
    outputFile.println("4");
    outputFile.println("It Spills Over The Sides");
    outputFile.println("It Bubbles Merrily");
    outputFile.println("Droplets Leap Out Like Goldfish Above The Surface");
    outputFile.println("Droplets Whizz Through The Air At High Speeds");
    outputFile.println("2");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");

    outputFile.println("How mamy brothers does Ron have?");
    outputFile.println("3");
    outputFile.println("3");
    outputFile.println("7");
    outputFile.println("5");
    outputFile.println("2");
    outputFile.println("0");
    outputFile.println("0");

    outputFile.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't you get any error message at all? Almost sounds like you have a breakpoint on line 12 and are debugging instead of running...

Comment: `while(inputFile.hasNextLine())` exhausts the `inputFile`; there aren't any more lines to read after that.